# Pre-generate Entity Framework Code First Views for performance without EF Powertools

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-performance, visual-studio-express

Is there any method of pre-generating EF Code first views without using EF Powertools?

I'm using Visual Studio Express - so the option of Powertools is not available.

I'm having problems of 10-15 second delays on the first query when the site is cold (which as a non public facing site happens quite often)

I'm already using the IIS warm up side of things and the app pool is always warm.

Once warm the site responds very quickly.  The issue only occurs on the first page with a query and that can be any query.

Comment: I've found this blog which gives information on creating / using T4Templates to pre generate the views: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/10/17/entity-framework-6-and-pre-generated-views/

At present due to bugs in EF6 RC1 apparently it's not possible to generate views for this version of the framework.

So I think at present I might be better creating a service that calls the default page every 5 minutes or so - unless any better solutions are presented.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a feeling that the problems you are seeing may not be related to generating views. There were some performance regressions that affected the start up time of EF6. We (the EF team) have been looking at them. Try a recent nightly build where the bugs are fixed to see if the start up time improved. In addition I updated the T4 template you are referring to to work with the final version of EF6. It should also work with the nightly builds so you should be able to verify if pre-generated views improve your start up time even further. Note that the T4 is not on the VS Gallery yet but you can get the source from my [github](https://github.com/moozzyk/EF6CodeFirstViewGenT4TemplateCSharp). I am planning to update the version of VS Gallery soon.

Comment: Thanks Pawel I will give that a go - well done on spotting my post!

Comment: Is there anyway of getting the latest nightly build of EF 6 rather than EF 6.1 - which is an Alpha? Thanks

Comment: Currently the only nightly is Alpha.